# Load or shuffle a pair of floats with SIMD intrinsics for doubles?

Tags: c, sse, simd, intrinsics, avx

I write some optimizations for processing single precision floating-point calculation SIMD intrinsics.

Sometimes a `pd` double-precision instruction does what I want more easily than any `ps` single precision one.

***Example 1:***

I have pointer **float* prt** which point to block of floats:
*f0 f1 f2 f3 etc.*

I want to load __m256 value with [ f0, f1, f0, f1, f0, f1, f0, f1 ]. I didn't find a 64-bit broadcast for `__m256` data types. Can I use `_mm256_broadcast_sd` on floats?

```
float* ptr = ...; // pointer to some memory chunk aligned to 4 bytes
__m256 vat = _mm256_castpd_ps( _mm256_broadcast_sd( ( double* )ptr ) );
```

***Example 2:***

I have __m256 value [f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7].
Can I use shift instructions like a _mm256_srl_epi32, which take as argument __m256i values for manipulation with my __m256 value?

I check it in practice and it works, but is it a correct way to use instructions with different types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `vbroadcastsd` is a good asm instruction for broadcasting a pair of floats, and `_mm256_broadcast_sd` + a cast intrinsic is a safe way to implement it in C.

Note that you aren't dereferencing (in pure C) a `double*` that points at `float` objects.  You're only passing it to an intrinsic function.  `_mm256_set1_pd( *(double*)floatp )` *would* be strict aliasing undefined behaviour in C, but load/store intrinsics are defined to work regardless of what the pointer is actually pointing at.  Exactly so you can easily do wide loads/stores to whatever data you actually have, not just `__int64` or `double`.

For example, GCC's header defines `_mm256_broadcastsd(const double*)` as a wrapper around `__builtin_ia32_vbroadcastsd256`.  And GCC defines `_mm_loadl_epi64` to include a dereference of `*(__m64_u *)__P`, where `__m64_u` is an unaligned may-alias version of `__m64` which it defines as.

```
typedef int __m64_u __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (8), __may_alias__, __aligned__ (1)));
```

(See also [Is `reinterpret_cast`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112605/is-reinterpret-casting-between-hardware-simd-vector-pointer-and-the-correspond))

**In general, even load/store intrinsics that take a `float*` or `double*` (instead of `__m128i*`) are alignment and strict-aliasing safe.**  (Or at least I think they're supposed to be.  On some compilers there might be some which aren't actually strict-aliasing safe.  So it can be a pain to get them to safely emit `vpbroadcastd` from a pointer that isn't actually pointing at an `int`, for example; I forget which intrinsic it was that found some compiler not respecting possible aliasing for.)

---

Your example 2 is not clear.  Are you wanting to bit-shift the bit-patterns of floats?  Yes, of course you can do that, that's why SIMD cast intrinsics exist to keep the C compiler happy when you want to reinterpret the same bits as a different vector type.

It's common to do that as part of implementing `exp()` or `log` for example, such as [Fastest Implementation of Exponential Function Using AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863719/fastest-implementation-of-exponential-function-using-avx)